# Не работает триггер

Tags: mysql, триггер

У меня есть таблица `ammo`, и, когда добавляют данные в эту таблицу, строки, где поле `price` больше 1000, должны уменьшаться на 50. Но такого не происходит:

```
delimiter &
create trigger LowPriceToAmmo after insert on ammo
for each row
begin
  declare i int;
  declare countI int;
  declare countAmmo int;
  select count(ammo.price) into countI from ammo;
  set @i:= 1;
  while @i > countI do
    select ammo.price into countAmmo from ammo where id = @i;
    if(countAmmo > 1000) then
      update ammo set price = price - 50  where id = @i;
    end if;
    set @i:= @i +1;
  end while;
end&
```

Comment: Еще раз: после добавления новой записи в таблицу `ammo`, надо чтобы в таблице ВСЕ записи с `price>=1000` были уменьшены на 50? Правильно я понял?

Comment: @cyadvert да. Вы все правильно поняли

Comment: Тогда зачем Вам такой сложный триггер? Почему просто не запустить обычный `UPDATE`? `UPDATE ammo SET price=price-50 WHERE price>=1000`?

Comment: @makintosh В mysql переменная `@i` никакого отношения к `i`, которая у вас объявлена declare и пытается использоваться в while, не имеет. переменные с собакой и переменные без собаки сделаны для абсолютно разных задач.

Comment: @cyadvert Я прохожу учебную практику по mysql

Comment: @Mike Спасибо. Сейчас попробую

Comment: @Mike Ничего не происходит(((

Comment: А что именно вы сделали, поправьте что ли текст триггера в вопросе на текущий вариант

Comment: @Mike поправил!

Comment: @makintosh У вас `Select count(ammo.price) into countI from ammo;` вернет кол-во записей в таблице. И `while 1 > кол-во` никогда не отработает. вернее она уйдет в бесконечный цикл если в таблице не будет записей. Ну и `where id=@i` сомнительное решение, никто не сказал что в таблице id идут с 1 и без разрывов, особенно если одну запись удалят а другую потом добавят.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не сможете в триггере обновить при помощи `UPDATE` ту же самую таблицу, к которой привязан триггер. Лучше выполнить такое обновление отдельным запросом.